# Html2pdf error when downloading a pdf file in remote server

Tags: php, pdf, yii, html2pdf

I'm using yii with html2pdf version 4.03 for downloading pdf documents in my project. The pdf documents consist of tables with many rows because they are reports. In my localhost, the download is fine. But when I do that in remote server, it can't be downloaded.

I used Firefox to download it. When I downloaded it, it prompted an alert message saying that I can't download because the source file cannot be read. When I force to download it (by pressing refresh button in firefox's download list), the pdf file is there. When I tried to open it, it says that the file is corrupted.

If I delete a few rows, it can be downloaded just fine. Strangely, even if I didn't delete the rows, they are still in one page. So the problem shouldn't be about "table row that doesn't fit in one page", should it?

What could be the problem? Could anyone help me with this please?

**UPDATES**

when I print it in browser instead of downloading, firefox prompts an error like below:

```
Content Encoding Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Still don't know how to solve this though...

Answer (score 0):

Save the generated pdf, open it in text editor, and see what error message is there.

Comment: I opened it as you suggested but it doesn't contain the pdf file at all. In fact, it contains html tags of the page where the download pdf button resides.

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing :(